# gradle multiple projects structure - best practice

Tags: svn, jenkins, gradle, dependency-management, release-management

I am new to gradle build. I have multi java projects which are dependent and I am looking for best practice to organize them in subversion so that i can move to CI.

The dependencies are:

ProjectA - [client1, manager, base]
ProjectB - [client2, manager, base]

base - [model]
model - [core]

Right now i am doing release of the dependencies and rolling up the versions manually in build.gradle file of the parent projects and releasing. Can anybody please guide me to best practices in such scenarios. Where it would be easy to eventually migrate to CI.

Thank you in advance.

Below is the structure of my svn

```
|--ProjectA //WAR artifact
|    |--trunk
|    |    |--src
|    |    |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |--branches
|    |    |--#12345
|    |
|    |--tags
|    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |
|    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |--0.0.2
|
|--ProjectB //WAR artifact
|    |--trunk
|    |    |--src
|    |    |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |--branches
|    |    |--#12345
|    |
|    |--tags
|    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |
|    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |--0.0.2
|
|--common
|    |
|    |--core //Jar artifact
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |
|    |    |--branches
|    |    |    |--#12345
|    |    |
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |
|    |--model //Jar artifact
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |
|    |    |--branches
|    |    |    |--#12345
|    |    |
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |
|    |--base //Jar artifact
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |
|    |    |--branches
|    |    |    |--#12345
|    |    |
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |
|    |--manager //Jar artifact
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |
|    |    |--branches
|    |    |    |--#12345
|    |    |
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |
|    |--client1 //Jar artifact
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |
|    |    |--branches
|    |    |    |--#12345
|    |    |
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |
|    |--client2 //Jar artifact
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |
|    |    |--branches
|    |    |    |--#12345
|    |    |
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--releaseCandidates
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.1
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
|    |    |    |
|    |    |    |--releases
|    |    |    |    |--0.0.2
```